# Kickstart Partitions

Tags: centos, kickstart

Hi I wrote the kickstart file for centos 7. It works great but in some machines because of partitioning 2 disk drives which should be determined like **sda** and **sdb** I have issues USB boot drive is overridden and interrupt the installation.

example:
PC1

```
installation is disk loaded like :
sda - crutial 1TB
sdb - crutial 2TB
sdc - USB boot drive

kickstart want format a parted sda and sdb and successfully instaled
```

PC2

```
instalation is disk loaded like :
sda - USB boot drive
sdb - crutial 1TB
sdc - crutial 2TB

kickstart wants format a parted sda, sdb, and kickstart formatted boot drive
```

Is here any possibility of how to exclude a USB drive from partitioning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to solve this is to network boot (PXE); this lowers the odds of
a stray USB device complicating the disk layout. However, `sda` `sdb`
are not stable and may change around (or not be present) at the whims of
the BIOS or who knows what, even if a USB device is not present.

Another, more complicated, way is to build the kickstart configuration
from within the kickstart configuration by means of a `%pre` script; the
output of the script is `%include`-ed into the configuration:

```
%include /tmp/ks-custom

%pre

function commify { local IFS=,; echo "$*"; }

# figure out what disks to use
declare -a drives
pushd /sys/block
test -e sda && for x in sd*
do
    # TODO determine if disk is usable, if so put on drives array
    drives+=($x)
done
popd

# emit kickstart configuration
if ((${#drives[@]})); then
    cat <<EOF >>/tmp/ks-custom
ignoredisk --only-use=$(commify ${drives[@]})
# TODO other kickstart partition commands, if need be
EOF
fi

%end
```

Comment: Thank you unfortunately I cant use PXE, I will try %pre script